# How to use SingleCompile, the vim plugin, to compile and run c in current split window instead of back to bash window?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

i used SingleCompile[singlecompile](https://github.com/xuhdev/SingleCompile),the vim plugin to compile and run code. 
it work fine,but i want to tune it to show the compile error message and result with splitting current window like 
[image: [this_result]
<sub>(source: [topbug.net](http://www.topbug.net/post-files/2012-03-07-use-singlecompile-to-compile-and-run-a-single-source-file-easily-in-vim/2.png))</sub>
].

i follow the [instruction](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2012/03/07/use-singlecompile-to-compile-and-run-a-single-source-file-easily-in-vim/) step by step,but when i hit F5 to compile and run the code, vim jump out from current window to bash,show the result and `press ENTER or type command to continue`,it also seems to has something to do with the buffer problem,because the previous compile messages were not be erased.

attach my vim-version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012 04:25:35)
Included patches: 1-429
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    +arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
+mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

my vimrc:

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"                       General                            "        
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/L9'
Plugin 'Rip-Rip/Clang_complete'
Plugin 'othree/vim-autocomplpop'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'Townk/vim-autoclose'
Plugin 'xuhdev/SingleCompile'
call vundle#end()

filetype indent plugin on
syntax on


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"                       Vim user interface                 "         
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
set number
set hidden
set ignorecase
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set cursorline 
""Don't redraw while executing macros (good performance config)
set lazyredraw

""source  /etc/vim/Auto_SetTitle.vim

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"                     Colors and Fonts                     "         
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

colorscheme ir_black
set t_Co=256
set guifont=Monaco\ 12
highlight Pmenu ctermbg=240 ctermfg=48
highlight PmenuSel ctermbg=99
highlight CursorLine   ctermbg=239 ctermfg=NONE

set laststatus=2
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"                       Useful shortcuts                   "        
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Set key combination's map leader
let mapleader = ","

nmap <F4> :SCCompile<cr>
nmap <F5> :SCCompileRun<cr>

let g:SingleCompile_menumode = 2
let g:SingleCompile_split = 'tabe'
set switchbuf=split

set showcmd     " Show (partial) command in status line.
set incsearch       " Incremental search
set tabstop=3
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=3
set expandtab

set wildmode=list:longest,full

"Clang_complete And  Supertab"
let g:clang_snippets=1
let g:clang_conceal_snippets=1
" The single one that works with clang_complete
let g:clang_snippets_engine='clang_complete'
"
" " Complete options (disable preview scratch window, longest removed to aways
" " show menu")
set completeopt=menu,menuone
"
" Limit popup menu height
set pumheight=20

" SuperTab completion fall-back 
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType='<c-x><c-u><c-p>'
```

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot was taken on GVim or MacVim, not in a terminal emulator.

When you run Vim in a terminal, going back to the shell is unavoidable without serious hacking. The whole process can be made slightly smoother by using `silent` somewhere in the command actually executed by that plugin but that's something you should talk about with its maintainer on the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/xuhdev/SingleCompile/issues).

Well, more generally, if you have a problem with a plugin, using its issue tracker or getting in touch with its author is a lot more useful for you and everyone than asking here.